# How to get the select option value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a select option just like below.

```
<select name = "type">
 <option value="">Select one</option>
 <option value="1">Abc</option>
 <option value="2">Xyz</option>
</select>
```

I tried to get the value using `Input::get('type')`But getting the labels `Abc`. I need to get the value as `1` or `2` or `3` depending on the one that I'm selecting. I even tried this

```
<select name = "type" onchange="document.getElementById('typeId').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

But same thing happened. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure? When I try `dd(Input::get('type'));` I get the selected value!

Comment: I need the `1` not the `Abc`

Comment: As for me it's return the value of selected. Yeah, it's `1` if you selected `Abc`

Comment: Strange! I get the `Abc` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just

```
document.getElementById('typeId').value=this.value;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. How can I do this in laravel easily? Any idea?

Comment: Actually I'm getting wrong value in the hidden input.

Comment: No, the solution is wrong. If the first option value is `6`, it gives the output as `1`.

Comment: Updated. Is what you were looking for?